# Android :Device taking too much time to respond with SQLite

Tags: android, android-layout

I am new to android and creating hello world application in eclipse.It is running successfully.But now I am using SQLite database and just creating DB,inserting values in it and displaying data in text view.but I ma getting this messages on console.:-

```
[2011-06-13 13:44:24 - SQLite] ------------------------------
[2011-06-13 13:44:24 - SQLite] Android Launch!
[2011-06-13 13:44:24 - SQLite] adb is running normally.
[2011-06-13 13:44:24 - SQLite] Performing com.ei.Main activity launch
[2011-06-13 13:44:24 - SQLite] Automatic Target Mode: launching new emulator with compatible AVD 'device'
[2011-06-13 13:44:24 - SQLite] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'device'
[2011-06-13 13:44:36 - SQLite] New emulator found: emulator-5554
[2011-06-13 13:44:36 - SQLite] Waiting for HOME ('') to be launched...
```

Then it takes too much time to respond and finally I got this as error message:-

```
[2011-06-13 13:40:23 - SQLite] emulator-5554 disconnected! Cancelling 'com.ei.Main activity launch'!
```

I am using AVD of Android 1.5 and application is also having same version 1.5.
Please help if you know how to resolve this issue.
Thanks in advance...

Comment: Without some code nobody can help ...

Comment: I think the error is not much concerned with the code.Since even I am not able to get .apk file and even home activity is not launched..

Answer (score 2):

Seems like the emulator issue. Android emulators are in general very slow, and it depends on your computer configuration. Only thing I can recommend you is not closing your emulator after every run. Keep it running during your coding time, this will save you a lot of time. And of course you should look forward to purchasing a real device, that's the best solution of this problem. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for reply...!!!But I tried not to close device after every run but it was giving me the error something like :- "emulator already in use."